# How to wire 2.5 inch wall sconce when junction box in 4 inch in size

Tags: electrical, wiring, walls

We have a couple of wall sconces to install that have 2.5 inch bases.
[image]
[image]

In the wall we have standard 4 inch round junction boxes.
[image]

How can we go about this install?

It doesn't seem like smaller junction boxes(under 4'') even exist and I don't think pulling the wire out from drywall right into the fixture is compliant with code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the sconce base showing measurements?

Comment: So is your issue fixing a small base to a large hole? One possibility is to make a base of wood or similar to fit the 4" and provide the support to the sconce.

Comment: When I've installed outside lights, the mounting screws have always been on a smaller radius than the mounting screws in the junction box. Each light fixture I've had has come with an adapter plate that has 2 holes for mounting to the fixture and slots for mounting to the box. Double check your parts/instructions.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your fixture?  I wonder if it's mean to be wall-mounted, with lamp cord rather than direct to a box.  Otherwise I would expect it to come with its own plate or adapter that makes it look attractive.

Comment: Added pictures of the base @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact

Comment: Added pictures of the fixture @jay613

Comment: Can you post a picture showing he base of the fixture unwrapped? Trying to see how it is *supposed* to mount - e.g., distance between screw holes or clips or whatever.

Comment: You might be able to find a suitable [canopy](https://www.grandbrass.com/category/canopies/). Can you add a photograph of the mounting side of the sconce?

Comment: Thanks for the picture.  What about instructions?  Did it come with instructions?  The picture of the fixture mounted to a wall with no cord, no box, and no cover plate seems to be misleading.  Sure, you could do it various ways but none of them easy or safe.  There are identical lamps for sale with square cover plates but they don't look as clean as this.  Does it have it's own special recessed box like eg a mini spot?  Instructions would help.

Answer (score 5):

A reducing mud ring

[image]

(Image from Gordon Electric supply - no affiliation)

Or a fixture ring

[image]

(image from Antique Lamp Supply - no affiliation.)

Answer (score 1):

So this is what the manufacturer suggests:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Apparently the housing of this thing can serve as a junction box.

Comment: That does not meet the usual specs for a junction box because of the large open space and "wire just stuck through". Typically a junction box (whether separate or as part of a fixture) will have a "just big enough" hole and some sort of clamping mechanism. The cable coming through the wall in the picture also does not look like typical cable for in-wall use.

Comment: So the instructions begin with a suitably connected lamp cord protruding conveniently from a hole in the wall.  That sure helps!!

Comment: I'd like to design a ceiling fan that can be installed that way.  I'll make a killing.   Just find a piece of wire already dangling from the ceiling and screw it on right there! :)

Comment: I'm glad you were able to answer your own question, apparently by _reading the manufacturer's instructions_.